# Calling Variable outside the Scope of "Request" in Request npm. at node.js

Tags: node.js, http, request-npm

```
var request = require('request');

request("http://example.com/index.php?username=username&password=password, function (error, response, body) {



var n1 = body.search('<user>');
var n2 = body.search('</user>');
var final = body.slice(n1+6, n2);


//it is working perfectly here. 
final10 = final;


 });

//The problem is that i can not call the "body" or variable "Final10" outside the Scope.

var final10=request.body
```

Hi, 
I am Newbie in Node JS.
I am trying to make a Experimental Bot. i am using "request" to send a "Get" to my website. there through "Php", it is getting saved in "Mysqli" database.

Everything is working fine and i am getting the result. 
but, as i had got the data required, i can not access it. 
How can i get access to the 'body' of 'Request' from outside the function?

Please refer above to the code

Is there any way, to call it outside of it? that i can manage my code more easily

Please Note: it is just a little snap of the code the real code. the real code got a lot of if/else, loops and other functions.
Turing it into bracket under brackets will be little complicated.

Thankyou

Comment: This is just a typical asynchronous callback issue in node.js.  Any code that uses the result of the asynchronous code must be either INSIDE the callback itself or in a function you call from that callback.  `request()` is non-blocking, so the calback itself is called long AFTER the code follow it is.  So, you're trying to use a variable before it's even been set.  Move the code inside the callback.

Comment: FYI, there are hundreds of similar questions here.  A search for nodejs, asynchronous callback will probably turn up lots of similar issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is more preferable, if i can get it where it is. it will just save me from a lot of work. But, if nothing works. i will surely follow your advise. Thank you again

Comment: With a plain callback, there is no other choice - that's how it works.  If you use an http request library that supports promises such as `got()`, you can use `await` and write more sequential looking code - you will have to switch libraries and learn a bit about proper use of promises in Javascript (it will be worth it).  You may also want to know that the `request()` library has been deprecated and is in maintenance mode (no new features coming).  I personally wouldn't use it in a new project.

Comment: Yup, i just checked it in "NPM" today and i really agree with you. but, i am new into it, so it is really a lot simpler than other libraries. But, i think, i do not have option, i will look into new libraries or will try await. .

Comment: `request()` is not simpler than other libraries that use promises.  I find `got()` easier and simpler to use and I can use it with `async/await` which fixes the issue you're asking about too.  This is just a matter of you learning something new that you will want to know anyway for development in node.js.

Comment: I will check it out. Thankyou Jfriend00..

Answer (score 1):

So the request function is asynchronous, which means that you call `request("http://...")` and node js fires that function, and then skips to the next line without waiting for it to finish. So if you had:

```
request("http://example.com/index.php?username=username&password=password", function() {
   console.log("1");
});

console.log("2");
```

You would see `2` logged before `1`. Which brings us to the function that is the second argument of request: the callback function. You are passing in a function for request to call, *once it has finished making the api request to your url*. So if we change the above example to:

```
request("http://example.com/index.php?username=username&password=password", function() {
   console.log("1");
   console.log("2");
});
```

You would see `1` logged before `2`.

Request takes the function you pass in and **injects the parameters: error, response and body** which you can work with inside the callback function.

Because you are working with request through a callback function here, which gets called asynchronously, you can only use `body` **within the callback function**.

```
request("http://example.com/index.php?username=username&password=password", function(error, response, body) {
   // do something with the response body
   console.log("Logging the response body", body);
});
```

You need to access the body within the *scope* of the callback function.

Comment: Firstly,Thankyou for your Answer


Yes, that is exactly the problem. Can we use any loops+ if/else statement to keep repeating the code until request is complete and then declare the variable?.

I really apologize, if it sounds stupid, since i am newbie in Node js.

Comment: What is your end goal? What do you plan to do with the variable final10